# Meaning of the phrase "treats of" in the title of chapter 1 of Oliver Twist

Tags: meaning-in-context, charles-dickens

The title of chapter 1 of Oliver Twist is as follow:

"Treats of the place where Oliver Twist was born...".

What is the exact meaning of the plural word "treats"? I assume it means something like "argumentation" however I have not been able to find the exact word (in plural form) in any dictionary. Is it an archaic word?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: It's [definition 1.2 in oxforddictionaries](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/treat): *Present or discuss (a subject)*, which I consider General Reference here on ELU.

Comment: Cf "treatise"..

Comment: @FumbleFingers Is this example a verb? I would read it as a verb if it wasn't followed by *of*, but it looks weird to me! Of course, I don't have access to the rest of the book or title right now. Also WS2 deosn't seem to agree with you at all in his comment above.

Comment: @Araucaria: The context is [Victorian English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+treats+of&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhich%20treats%20of%3B%2Cc0), and as you'll see from that NGram, the preposition ***of*** was commonly used in such contexts a century or two ago. I wouldn't call it "archaic", but *[some text] treats **of** [some theme]* is at the very least "dated, formal".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ah, I see why Luca couldn't identify it now :) Thanks!

Comment: The [OED](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/205381#eid17737795) doesn't come right out and hit it with the '[death dagger](http://oed.hertford.ox.ac.uk/main/content/view/73/183/)' (for 'obsolete') but their most recent cite is 1874. It may not be quite gone yet but it's definitely *going* the way of the dinosaurs.

Comment: Similar question on ELL: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/44557/8712

Answer (score 2):

'Treats of' means 'explains' or 'describes'. It's archaic now.

[**treat**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/treat)

> VERB [with object]
>
> 1.2 Present or discuss (a subject)

Oxford Dictionaries. Oxford University Press, n.d. Web. 09 January 2015.

Comment: Thanks I erroneously assumed it was a noun and not a verb. I was deceived by a similar verbal construction in my native language which uses a noun in similar contexts instead of a verb.

Comment: No worries, @LucaRegini. It's not something you'd normally see in print nowadays, plenty of native English speakers would be unfamiliar with 'treat' in that particular usage.

Answer (score 2):

It's not in plural form because it has an added *s* which is only done with verbs in the 3rd person singular:

> I treat, you treat, he/she/it treats, we treat, you treat, they treat.

And from there it reduces down a general reference as we just have to [look up *treat*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/treat#Verb):

> To discourse on; to represent or deal with in a particular way, in writing or speaking

Being a subtitle, the omitted subject is the work itself. So it's equivalent to "This chapter treats of the…".

Comment: Or is it a noun form which is being used? As in "treatise".

Comment: @WS2 that wouldn't make the rest of the sentence work well though. Also, the pattern of starting with a verb (hence having the chapter as an omitted subject) is followed in other subtitles in the same work.

Comment: Yes. That does seem a familiar 19th-century style.